# Event listener that "camera and microphone blocked" is allowed

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia

By getUserMedia, it is possible that UserMedia is blocked by user.

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        ...
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.usermedia_blocked = true;
      });
```

When the setting is changed to "always allow", I want to continue the subsequent task.
But how can I detect that "always allow & done" is clicked?

[image]

Appear.in start video call after "always allow & done " is clicked.
I want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

appear.in developer here. What do is to poll navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices(), check if we have device labels on the camera and microphone (which implies permission has been re-granted) and then call getUserMedia again.

Comment: thank you very much! I have implemented by using polling. but there is a bit difference. (1)check suported device by enumerateDevices(), '(2) check permission by getUserMedia (3) if it is blocked start polling getUserMedia for each 500 msec.

Comment: 2021 update, FF doesn't reset labels to empty strings any more after blocking access...