# Detect removal of restriction of devices

Tags: javascript, media, mediadevices

Using [*getUserMedia*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) to let user select microphone. Further I use [*enumerateDevices*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) to create a select with devices so that user can change device from UI.

I am on Firefox and have not checked how others browsers fare, but at least for FF I have not found a solution.

If user selects to not allow access when asked one do not get to ask again<sup>[ 1 ]</sup> until user removes the restriction:

[image]

Question is if there is a way to detect when user removes the restriction?

Scenario is typically:

1. User loads page and are asked to select input device
2. User rejects

   ```
   UI disables device selector + hide various stuff
   ```
3. User removes restriction (as per picture above)

   ```
   UI enables device selector + unhide various stuff
   ```

There is (obviously) not a way to reset the block from client side by Java Script, but is there a way to detect that user revokes the block? (Or is there? Sounds like something that could be exploited to keep looping a request for access.)

One could do a loop where one keep trying for the lifetime of the page, but would like to avoid that. Looking for an event for this.

In that regard, [ondevicechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/ondevicechange), does not trigger an event when block is removed - which is logical in a way as there is not a change in the available devices, in a way :P.

---

<sup>[ 1 ]</sup> That is: one can ask, but it result in a:

> **MediaStreamError**
>   *message:* The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context.
>   *name:* [NotAllowedError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Exceptions)
>   ​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to detect this change from the [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions).

The [PermissionStatus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus) object returned by [`Permissions.prototype.query()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query) has an `onchange` event handler. So a query to the `"camera"` or `"microphone"` will fire its change event when the user changes their setting.

```
const camera_perm = await navigator.permissions.query( { name: 'camera' } );
camera_perm.onchange = (evt) => {
  const allowed = camera_perm.state === "granted";
  if( allowed ) {
    // ...
  }
  else {

  }
};
```

This currently [works in Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/nwc2adh7/), but Firefox still doesn't support neither the `"camera"` nor the `"microphone"` members of *PermissionDescriptor*.
So for that browser, the closest we can have is through polling, as explained in this Q/A: [Event listener that "camera and microphone blocked" is allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095851/event-listener-that-camera-and-microphone-blocked-is-allowed) .

Comment: Nice. That was what I was looking for. Too bad FF is lagging, but at least know a place to keep an eye on the progress. One could perhaps, in the meantime, have used `navigator.permissions.revoke` as an optional fallback, but that one requires user enabling, so very likely not active.